# How to get style transform rotate value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, rotation, transform, return-value

I need transform rotate value...? alert("rotate(30deg)")...

```
<div id="demo" style="transform: rotate(30deg);width:100px;height:50px;background-color:red;">
```

```
var myElement = document.getElementById("demo");
var rotate = getElementById("demo").style.transformRotate.value;
alert(rotate);
```

Comment: You mean, the output should be `30deg`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could parse the `transform` style using [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to get the rotate value:

```js
var myElement = document.getElementById("demo");
var rotate = myElement.style.transform.match(/rotate\((.+)\)/);
alert(rotate && rotate[1]);  // avoid error if match returns null
```

```html
<div id="demo" style="transform: rotate(30deg);width:100px;height:50px;background-color:red;">
```

To separate the number (30) from the unit (deg), you could do the following:

```js
var myElement = document.getElementById("demo");
var rotate = myElement.style.transform.match(/rotate\((\d+)(.+)\)/);
if (rotate) {
  var [num, unit] = rotate.slice(1);  // slice is needed since first element contains entire match
  console.log('num:', num, 'unit:', unit);
}
```

```html
<div id="demo" style="transform: rotate(30deg);width:100px;height:50px;background-color:red;">
```

Comment: Can you edit and get split var num = 30 and var = deg(or...) ?

Comment: Nice!, just a minor improvement for if you have additional transforms : `rotate\((\d+)([^)]+)\)`  that way the selection will not grab all the rest of the string and stop at the last parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

You need to store `transform` not `transformRotate`:

```js
var myElement = document.getElementById("demo");
var transformation = myElement.style.transform;
alert(transformation);
```

```html
<div id="demo" style="transform: rotate(30deg);width:100px;height:50px;background-color:red;">
```